# Can I directly consider the Hive partition columns similar to the partitions columns present in source (Teradata) tables?

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning

Can I directly consider the Hive partition columns similar to the partitions columns present in my source (Teradata) tables? or do I have consider any other parameters to decide the Hive partitioning columns ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not best practice. if you create data in this manner then a person who is trying to access HDFS data directly will not find 'partition columns' in each partition. For example say Teradata table is partitioned by `date` column then if hive table is also partitioned by `date` then HDFS partition say 2016-08-06 will not have date field. So to make it easy for end user partition by a dummy column say `date_d` which will exactly same values as date column.

Answer (score 0):

- Abstractly, partitioning in Teradata and Hive are similar.To begin
  with  you can probably use the same columns as in your source to
  partition the tables.

  If you data size is huge in each single partition, then consider
  partitioning it further, to improve the performance.The multilevel
  partitioning would mostly depend on the number of filters you apply
  on your queries.